# How is PrimaryScrollController used in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to take advantage of the iOS feature where the scroll view scrolls to the top when the status bar is tapped.

I'm using a ListView and according to the docs, the *primary* attribute determines this behavior, but I need to initialize my ListView with a ScrollController, and an error is thrown:

> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart': Failed assertion: line 62 pos 15: '!(controller != null && primary == true)'

I have a tabbed app with a ListView on each tab, so I need to explicitly create ScrollController objects and use them to initialize the ListView objects.

The PrimaryScrollController widget might allow me to designate a ScrollController as primary, but I can't find any examples of it being used. More specifically, I don't understand what the child attribute of PrimaryScrollController needs to be. An example of PrimaryScrollController's use would be extremely helpful.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12764) might help you

Comment: This helps but is there a way to give the PrimaryScrollController an initial offset? I'd like to be able to initialize attributes of the ScrollController I'm using, but using PrimaryScrollController.of(context) doesn't allow this. Are there any examples that use the PrimaryScrollController constructor?

Comment: Consider adding [repro] to make this question better

Answer (score 1):

PrimaryScrollController identifies the controller of the widget on screen with a ScrollView. Even without setting the ScrollController to be controller of the ListView.

Here's an example of scrolling to the top from the bottom of the ListView.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sample Scroll'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        /// No controller configured
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Card(
              child: Container(
                height: 50.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Text('Item $index'),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          var controller = PrimaryScrollController.of(context);
          controller!.animateTo(controller.position.minScrollExtent,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 2), curve: Curves.ease);
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Demo]

If ScrollController is used, it should be configured on the ListView.

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var scrollController = ScrollController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sample Scroll'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          /// Configure ListView controller
          controller: scrollController,
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Card(
              child: Container(
                height: 50.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Text('Item $index'),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          scrollController.animateTo(scrollController.position.minScrollExtent,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 2), curve: Curves.ease);
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```